# Accessing First View Controller from Custom Keyboard Controller

Tags: ios

Here s the problem - I have implemented a custom keyboard - it s based on its view , with associated my keyboard.m and keyboard.h files. 
An IBAction clickKey is associated for each keyboard button.
I worked from this example

http://polythinking.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/how-to-add-custom-keyboard-at-ios-development/

I have also in my project a first view controller with textfields. Using delegate I ve succeeded in having the custom keyboard appear when those textfields on the first view are clicked.

Now, the question is :

In the my keyboard.m file I implement the clickKey method. But it needs access to the first view textfields.

myKeyboard.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


#define   keyZERO    0
#define   keyONE     1
#define   keyTWO     2
#define   keyTHREE   3
#define   keyFOUR    4
#define   keyFIVE    5
#define   keySIX     6
#define   keySEVEN   7
#define   keyEIGHT   8
#define   keyNINE    9

#define   keyDOT    10
#define   keyBACK   11
#define   keyDONE   12



@class FuelViewController;



@protocol myKeyboardDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) myKeyboardInput : (int) number;

@end




@interface myKeyboardView:UIView{

@private id<myKeyboardDelegate> _delegate;

}



@property (nonatomic,assign) id<myKeyboardDelegate> delegate;


-(IBAction)keyClick:(id)sender ; 


@end
```

myKeyboardView.m:

```
#import "myKeyboardView.h"


@implementation myKeyboardView

@synthesize delegate;
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}

-(IBAction)keyClick:(id)sender{

    int i = [sender tag];

     if ( i == keyDONE) {       }
}


@end
```

Comment: can you show the code that makes the keyboard view appear?